# Compare two binary strings consist only 0 and 1 in java, want to findout which string is lexicographically greater

Tags: java, string, binary, binary-data

this is what i am doing for comparing binary string but it is taking o(n) time in worst case. I have tried both manually and Strings compareTo method, Please help me with better approach to solve this problem--

by CompareTo method -

```
if (A.compareTo(temp) < 0) 
{
    System.out.println("YES");
}
else 
{ 
    System.out.println("NO"); 
}
```

By iterating strings:-

```
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
    if (A.charAt(k) == '1' && B.charAt(k) == '0') {
    System.out.println("NO");
    break;
} else if (B.charAt(k) == '1' && A.charAt(k) == '0') {
    System.out.println("YES");
    break;
}
```

see this is the complete --

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    int Q = sc.nextInt();
    String A = sc.next();
    StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder(sc.next());
    for (long i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
        int pos = sc.nextInt();
        B.setCharAt(pos - 1, '1');
        String temp = B.toString();
        if (A.equals(temp)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
                if (A.charAt(k) == '1' && B.charAt(k) == '0') {
                System.out.println("NO");
                break;
            } else if (B.charAt(k) == '1' && A.charAt(k) == '0') {
                System.out.println("YES");
                break;
            }
        } /*
             * else if (A.compareTo(temp) < 0) { System.out.println("YES");
             * } else { System.out.println("NO"); }
             */
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better approach"?

Comment: In the worst case the last bit makes the difference (or not i.e. the strings are equal) how should you know that before the end? That is I have doubts anything better than in O(n) exists. Or counter question who or what gave you the idea that there is a better solution? Reference?

Comment: O(n) is the best you can do without parallelism.

Comment: If i have to do parallelism , how i can implement it?

Comment: @jrook better approach means , less worst time complexity

Comment: @stickybit i am getting timed out for few test cases, i don't know why?

Comment: OK, then please edit your answer and state the this in there. Don't forget to provide the data for these test cases.

Answer (score -1):

You do two comparisons in each if condition. As it is guaranteed that `'0'<'1'` this can be simplified. Further you only need to have a detailed decision if the two characters to compare are not equal.

```
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
    if (A.charAt(k) != B.charAt(k))
    {
        System.out.println(A.charAt(k) < B.charAt(k)? "YES": "NO";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this improve time complexity?

Comment: in each iteration where  `A.charAt(k)== B.charAt(k)` you have only one comparison whereas the original Iteration has two (if both chars are `'0'`) or four (both chars are `'1'`).

Comment: I see, but it does not improve time complexity over O(n) which seems to be the problem OP wants a solution for.

Comment: The OP is looking for "better approach". Yes, it is still O(n), but IMHO still improved by factor 3.

Comment: How about just using compareTo as OP has mentioned? Are you claiming that your solution is better than using Java's compareTo  method?

Comment: I only reference to the iteration proposed of the OP - I never referenced to `compareTo`.

Comment: @milbrandt check the complete code which i have attached, is there any possibilities of improvement.